# Python: calling class to print Tweet contents

Tags: python, api, class, twitter

I'm trying to filter tweets by hashtag and output the text of the Tweet.

The class Tweet contains the overarching tweet info, of which I only need "text". I know that str method needs to be used to call each instance of the class, but down below when I "print", the above class is inaccessible. Please help :D

Edit: what's the implication of replacing `__str__` with `__repr__` in class Tweet? Thanks!

```
class Tweet():

    tweet = Tweet()
    def __init__(self, tweet_dict = {}):        
        if "statuses" in tweet_dict:
            self.status = tweet_dict["statuses"]
        else:
            self.status = ""

        if "text" in self.status:
            self.text = item["text"]
        else:
            self.text = ""

    def __str__(self):
        tweet_info = self.text
        return tweet_info

#-------------------------------------------------------------------

tweet_inst = []
for dic in statuses:
    item_instances = Tweet(dic)
    tweet_inst.append(item_instances)
print(tweet_inst)
```

Comment: Could you please fix the code block formatting? The `tweet = Tweet()` line looks fishy, but I can't tell if it is actually part of the class body. If it is, this will be one of your problems I guess.

Answer (score 0):

`__str__` needs to `return` a string representation of the object.

`__str__` goal is to be readable, `__repr__` goal is to be unambiguous.

When you print a list (*which is tweet_inst*), it iterates over the objects (*of Tweet*) contained in the list and call their `__repr__`.

You want to add `def __repr__(self): return str(self)` so they do the same thing, then it will return `self.text` instead of the object default representation (*which is it's location in memory*)

```
class Tweet(object):

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __str__(self):
        return self.x

    def __repr__(self):
        return '__repr__' + str(self.x)

>>> t1 = Tweet('t1')
>>> t2 = Tweet('t2')
>>> list_ = [t1, t2]
>>> print(list_)
[__repr__t1, __repr__t2]

Rather than the default
[<__main__.Tweet object at 0x02AFA810>, <__main__.Tweet object at 0x029E2BF0>]
```

[Here is a great answer by moshez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2626364/840582) about the difference between the two.

Comment: Actually, I think the OP does return tweet_info in `__str__`, just the formatting of the code block is broken, which is why I asked to fix it.

Comment: @shmee You're right, it was out of the code block, written in bold so I didn't notice.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the second line, `tweet = Tweet()` in the class definition is wrong. You cannot create a class variable containing an instance of said class.

Second, you assign `self.text = item["text"]` in line 11. What is `item`? Should that rather be `tweet_dict`?

Third, you could directly return `self.text` in `__str__`, no need to assign it to a varibale tweet_info first.

Last, but not least, you should not use mutable datatypes as default arguments, like you do in line 4. [Here's why.](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/mutable-default-arguments/)